# Is there a way to close select file window with selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, maven, testing, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to close this pop up window with selenium? When it appears I send the file to the driver using sendText. The file is well imported but the pop up is not closed.

When the driver is closed sometimes the pop up windows closes with the driver and sometimes don't, i didn't find why this happens.

I'm using Selenium with Java in maven.

If some one knows some way to interact with this window would be a great help!
Thank you!

[select file Window example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpT24.jpg)

Comment: You'd have to use something called Autoit to close and well as interacting with windows such as that.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium it self cannot interact with Windows.
What you can do for upload is to find the upload button and send the filepath to it.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your_id")).sendKeys("filepath");
```

In this case the Window should not be open.

Comment: Thank You! Its helpful. This way i don't have to click the interaction button.